# Javascript - Solid Colored Text Flash

Tags: javascript

Basically all I want to do is make text flash different colors. etc.  text flashes blue then red, then pink, then purple, etc.  Thanks in advance

Comment: So... what exactly are you having problems with? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS3 instead of Javascript. The sample below blinks from red to yellow, green, blue and back to red. Remember to add specific vendor prefixes for mozilla, webkit, etc. (e.g. *-moz-animation* and *-moz-keyframes*)

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blinking Text</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />      
</head>
<body>   
    <div class="test">Text</div>       
   </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.test
{
    font-size: 48pt;
    animation: 2s blink steps(1) infinite;  
}

@keyframes blink
{
    0% { color: red; }
    25% { color: yellow; }
    50% { color: green; }
    75% { color: blue; }
    100% {color: red; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jsfiddle. I've commented each part of the JS for instructional purposes: http://jsfiddle.net/VXRpz/

Answer (score 0):

```
function flashtext(ele,col) {
var tmpColCheck = document.getElementById( ele ).style.color;

  if (tmpColCheck === 'silver') {
    document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = col;
  } else {
    document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = 'silver';
  }
} 

setInterval(function() {
    flashtext('flashingtext','red');
    flashtext('flashingtext2','blue');
    flashtext('flashingtext3','green');
}, 500 ); //set an interval timer up to repeat the function
```